# Is it possible to override a method in same class in Java?

Tags: java, oop, inheritance, overriding

Take a look at the following code sample :

```
public class Test{

   public static void main(String[] args){

        System.out.println(new Test());


       System.out.println(new Test(){

        public String toString(){
             return "manual override";
         }

       });



      System.out.println(new Test(){

              public String gm(){
                    return  "manual gm";
               }
        }.gm());
     }  //end of main method

   public String gm(){
     return "gm";
    }
}
```

There may be some argument that the `toString()` method is being overridden in anonymous inner class which is an entirely different class.
But the overriding code still resides in the same class. So, will it be justified to conclude that in some situations [as described above] , the overriding of a method in same class is possible?

Comment: point you are making here will become a kind of "Overloading". Overriding has to be with different classes.

Comment: Well it's the same file, not the same class. Have you a real world use case that makes sense for something like that?

Comment: @AlpeshPrajapati If it was Overloading, then the program will not have printed "manual override". Besides for overloading, method signature must change- to be specific parameters must be changed to overload. But I haven't changed the method signature of toString method even a bit. I've updated the code sample to help you understand better.

Comment: @guido Here, I'm not going into any discussion of real world use case. I know the above code sample is not a very good design practice. But my question was in case such situation occurs, then what should be the conclusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is No, you cannot override the same method in one class. The anonymous inner class is a different class.

Comment: Yes. I know for the anonymous inner class, Test$1.class Test$2.class will be created. But what about the fact the overriding code resides in the same class body ? How will you explain that?

Comment: Many classes can exists in same class body (inner classes for that matter) and overriding rules applies to classes and not src files.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, you haven't defined toString in your `Test.java` class.

Secondly, when you make a anonymous class, its is conceptually like creating a subclass. So overriding in anonymous class is allowed as long as parent method is not final.

Mainly, overriding is NOT possible in same class otherwise.

Comment: I've updated the code sample. So, your very first point doesn't stand well with respect to updated code sample. So, what's your say about the updated code which defines a method in the same class & overrides it in the same class body with help of anonymous inner class?

Comment: still as i said in the second point, anonymous class is conceptually a dynamically created subclass. So, when you have overridden `gm()` method inside anonymous class, it is like overriding inside a subclass. So, you are never overriding in the same class. Even if you try to do it in the same class, compiler will not allow you to.

Answer (score 1):

The code above overrides **toString()** method of **Object** class. So you cannot say that it overrides in the same class. Now also it is overriding a superclass method and here the super class is **Object** which is the super class of all classes.

Comment: I've updated the code sample.Updates code sample demonstrates it's possible to override even Test class methods apart from those methods inherited from Object class.

Answer (score 0):

No , You can override a method in subclass only.

```
public String toString(){
         return "manual override";
     }
```

In your case you are overriding `Object's` `toString()` method not `Test` class method.

Comment: I've updated the code sample.Updates code sample demonstrates it's possible to override even Test class methods apart from those methods inherited from Object class.

Answer (score 0):

In one class we can not have method with same signature. 
this is because there is no need to have override method in same class.

hence overriding method in same class is not possible, where as if we want to use same method name we can overload method by changing signature.

Answer (score 0):

About the "real world use case," I do find a practical usage of the above program in section 2.5 of "JUnit Recipes" 2005 by Manning.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Counter {
private int count;
// a simple integer instance variable
public Counter( ) { }
// default constructor (count is 0)
public Counter(int initial) { count = initial; }
// an alternate constructor
public int getCount( ) { return count; }
// an accessor method
public void increment( ) { count++; }
// an update method
public void increment(int delta) { count += delta; }
// an update method
public void reset( ) { count = 0; }
// an update method
}
```

Isn;t this function overriding under same class??

Comment: No, this is overloading.

Comment: This is not an answer to the question: it is a question itself.